# To letter, then delete until letter, and repeat

Tags: vim

From "practical vim", I gather than a good practice is to try to move, act, and then repeat.

Say I have this string:

```
foo_bar fooo_bar foo abar foo_bar
```

I would like to move forwards until I find an `f`, and then delete until I find a `b`, and repeat.

I would have thought that the following would work:

```
ff
dtb
;
.
;
.
```

`ff` would be the command to move, and then `dtb` the one to act.

However, when I press `;`, it goes forwards until just before the next `b`, while I would like to repeat my "move" command, i.e. `ff`.

Is there a way to do this, such that the "act" command doesn't change the behaviour of the "move" one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could record a macro into some register and replay it. Using the `a`
register:

```
qaffdtbq
```

this breaks down into:

- `qa` to begin recording the macro into the `a` register
- `ffdtb` are the commands you wanted to run
- `q` to stop the recording

and then, with the cursor on the first character, run the macro 4 times with
`4@a` to change this:

```
foo_bar fooo_bar foo abar foo_bar
```

to this:

```
foo_bar bar bar bar
```

or just run the macro once with `@a` and then hit `@@` to repeat it

Answer (score 6):

`;` repeats the latest `fFtT` which, in your case, is `tb`, not `ff`. There is no way to make `;` repeat something else.

Here are alternative methods…

- With `:help /`:

  ```
  ff
  d/b<CR>    " delete until next b
  ;
  .
  ;
  .
  ```

  As mentioned by @mattb, the trick is to use a different motion than any of `fFtT` for the operation so that your `ff` is always the latest motion repeatable with `;` or `,`.
- With `:help recording`:

  ```
  qq         " start recording in register q
  ff
  dtb
  q          " stop recording
  @q         " play it back
  @q         " play it back
  ```

  The trick is to encapsulate the initial motion and the operation into a single macro that can be repeated over and over without involving `;` at all.

Comment: Ah nice idea to preserve the `;` 'memory' by using a search as an alternative to `f`!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not what you need, but you could do the same thing using the `:s` command.

```
:s/f[^ft]*t//g
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also search for the `f` with `/` and then jump to the next one with `n`:

Input:

```
foo_bar fooo_bar foo abar foo_bar
```

Actions:

```
/f<CR>
dtb
n
.
n
.
```

Result:

```
foo_bar bar bar bar
```